Install Ubuntu 24.04 under VirtualBox 7.1
I'm trying to install Ubuntu 24.04 under VirtualBox 7.1 as recommended by the User Guide. The installation fails with the following error message:
VirtualBoxVM.exe - Application error!  
The instruction at address 0x00007FF8214F9CB4 referenced memory address 0x0000020ADAD434D4.   
The following operation cannot be performed in the memory space: written.
Click OK to exit the program. 

There was no problem with the previous version of VirtualBox (7.0.20).
How can I finish the Ubuntu installation?

In that case, why not go back to the previous version of virtualbox?

Yes, it's true! If I withdraw, I'll have a working version of Ubuntu, but I'm not there yet! I've decided to try VirtualBox 7.1 (as new it can be buggy and in this case it's almost obvious), yet I don't want to believe that such an introductory (beginner) step as loading an op. system into a newly set up VirtualBox account should be buggy! And if anything, it's something that other VirtualBox and also Ubuntu users have run into, so I can legitimately expect a community experience.

Please report a bug with the virtualbox developers. It is not a Ubuntu issue

I’m voting to close this question because this is a virtualbox bug and not a Ubuntu bug

This is a valuable question because someone trying to use Ubuntu for the first time may reasonably encounter this incompatibility like me. Knowing the previous version works is highly valuable. When I tried all I got was a black video screen when booting the iso image of 24.04.1. These bugs may be in Virtualbox but they effect trying to run Ubuntu.
